# AngularJS Clicking on the link is opens the textarea

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I know that is function in css -> target but she change url address, I need do this effect without no url changes. And here is question, I know that I can do it in pure js, but the most important question is, can I do it in AngularJS ? If yes can someone explain me how to get this effect?

[IMAGE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ud5pq.png)

Thanks

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: I did it in CSS with :target but it change url where i wont it. I do not want to solve only hints on how to do it in AngularJS.

Comment: https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/examples/angularjs. please check this url, it might help you.

Comment: I need one thing, u gave me url for whole angular?:/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide an item from a div by clicking on it you can use "ngHide".

[For more information here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide)